# Iterating through a list's items in quotes in R

Tags: r, iteration, quotes

I am trying to iterate items from a list, which have quotation marks in their names. So far I have managed the following:

```
lm_uni1=matrix(nrow=100,ncol=2)
      for(i in 5:100){
      #t1.port.returns<-cbind(as.data.frame(stress.list$`item:i`[[1]]),
      #                       as.data.frame(stress.list$`item:i`[[2]]),
      #                       as.data.frame(stress.list$`item:i`[[3]]),
      #                       as.data.frame(stress.list$`item:i`[[4]])) 
      #The above iteration does not work because the i is between ` ` and thus
#it does not change over the iteration process.
#The next one tries to adjust for the issue:          
t1.port.returns<-cbind(
                cat(paste("stress.list$`item:",i,"`[[1]]",sep="")),
                cat(paste("stress.list$`item:",i,"`[[2]]",sep="")),
                cat(paste("stress.list$`item:",i,"`[[3]]",sep="")),
                cat(paste("stress.list$`item:",i,"`[[4]]",sep=""))
 )


              names(t1.port.returns)<-c("PortMU","PortS","PortA","PortN")
              AnaDataset<-as.data.frame(cbind(t1.port.returns,FF))
              names(AnaDataset)[6]<-"F5"
              seq1<-summary(lm(PortMU~RF+F1+F2+F3+F4+F5,data=AnaDataset))
              lm_uni1[i,1]<-seq1$coef[2,1]
              lm_uni1[i,2]<-seq1$coef[2,4]
              }
```

However `t1.port.returns` returns the following:

```
stress.list$`item:5`[[1]]stress.list$`item:5`[[2]]stress.list$`item:5`[[3]]stress.list$`item:5`[[4]]NULL
```

which is not the matrix of the data. The cat() does not help in accessing the data that are associated with the name of the list's item. Is there a way to address that issue?

The output of one of the items of the lists is:

```
> head(stress.list$`item:50`[[1]])
[1] 0.0005571963 0.0007163872 0.0006470110 0.0007732345 0.0012316404 0.0010932486
> length(stress.list$`item:50`[[1]])
[1] 189
```

Thus basically the output of the `t1.port.returns` should be like this:

```
>head(cbind(stress.list$`item:50`[[1]],stress.list$`item:50`[[2]],stress.list$`item:50`[[3]]))
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 0.0005571963 0.0005476554 0.0007157594
[2,] 0.0007163872 0.0007142794 0.0007953541
[3,] 0.0006470110 0.0007206310 0.0006402598
[4,] 0.0007732345 0.0008514236 0.0009244147
[5,] 0.0012316404 0.0012356093 0.0013711927
[6,] 0.0010932486 0.0009898300 0.0012163905
```

but when implementing the cat() to iterate over it, we do not the above output.

Comment: can you update your post with the list you are working with and post expected output for the same?

Comment: I added what you asked. It is impossible to add the list due to its huge size.